# Importing python package from child package

Tags: python, python-2.7

In this directory tree:

```
mod
| __init__.py
|-mod1
    |-__init__.py
    |-ceva.py
|-mod2
    |- __init__.py
    |-altceva.py
```

- All **__init__.py** files are empty.
- PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:PATH_TO_PARENT/mod
- **ceva.py** file contains the function that I need to import.

How can I import the function (from **ceva.py**), in **altceva.py** file ?

Doing `from mod.mod1.ceva import foo` in **altceva.py** seems to work, but only if I run `python mod2/altceva.py` from **mod** directory, but not from **mod/mod2**. How can I make the import available from both **mod** and **mod/mod2** paths ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to make your `mod` directory available to Python interpreter. If you are on MacOSX just do:

```
cd path_to_main_mod_directory
ln -s /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mod mod
```

then it will work:

```
python mod/mod2/altceva.py
cd mod && python mod2/altceva.py
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add mod to the PATH that the python interpreter uses.
As you know your own little file structure this can be done from with in the script itself.

**altceva.py**

```
import sys
import os

#Absolute path of mod2 directory
#__file__ is the location of this script
mod2_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realname(__file__))
#Absolute path of mod directory
mod_dir = os.path.dirname(mod2_dir)

#Add mod to PATH
sys.path.append(mod_dir)

from mod1.ceva import foo
```

That lets you import anything from the mod directory and you also don't need to put mod. at the start of your import.